While Building the Favorites Program in solana
    use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("");

pub const ANCHOR_DISCRIMINATOR_SIZE: usize = 8;

#[program]
pub mod favorites {

    use super::*;

    pub fn set_favorites(
        context: Context<SetFavorites>,
        number: u64,
        color: String,
        hobbies: Vec<String>,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        // Fill in later
        msg!("Greetings from {}", context.program_id);
        let user_public_key = context.accounts.user.key();

        msg!("User {user_public_key}'s favorite number is {number}, favorite color is {color}, and their hobbies are {hobbies:?}");

        context.accounts.favorites.set_inner(Favorites {
            number,
            color,
            hobbies,
        });

        Ok(())
    }

}

#[account]
#[derive(InitSpace)]
pub struct Favorites {
    pub number: u64,

    #[max_len(50)]
    pub color: String,

    #[max_len(5, 50)]
    pub hobbies: Vec<String>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SetFavorites<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = user,
        space = ANCHOR_DISCRIMINATOR_SIZE + Favorites,
        seeds = [b"favorites" , user.key().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub favorites: Account<'info, Favorites>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

I am getting this error and I have no clue how to solve this problem!


Just as the error message is telling you, you're trying to add a struct to a number, instead of another number. Deriving InitSpace defines an INIT_SPACE associated constant on your struct, which you should use like so:
space = ANCHOR_DISCRIMINATOR_SIZE + Favorites::INIT_SPACE,

Docs for reference: https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/space
